# Как сделать что бы в сообщении выводило логин пользователя из Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Не мог понять как мне вывести имя пользователя для чата в самом диалоге. Сейчас у меня выводит просто его сообщение, я хочу чтобы под каждым его сообщением была надпись его логина и вот тут что-то я знатно туплю, что не пишу - все не так. И, честно говоря, я уже просто запутался. Помогите, пожалуйста, как мне сделать, чтобы в сообщении выводило еще логин пользователя?
Вот код моего главного класса:

```
public class ChatOnline extends AppCompatActivity {
private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference myRef;
private DatabaseReference room;
private FirebaseUser currentUser;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

private Toolbar toolbar;
private RecyclerView recyclerMessage;
private Button sendBtn;
private EditText inputMessage;

private String messageUser;
private static int MAX_LENGTH_MESSAGE = 20;
private Boolean searchInterlocutor = false;

public ArrayList<String> messages;
private ChatAdapter chatAdapter;


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.chat_online_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_online);

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getInstance().getReference("Messages");
    currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    messages = new ArrayList<>();

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarChat);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    recyclerMessage = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerMessage);
    recyclerMessage.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ChatOnline.this));

    chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(this,messages);
    recyclerMessage.setAdapter(chatAdapter);

    inputMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputMessage);
    sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
    sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            messageUser = inputMessage.getText().toString();
            if(messageUser.equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(ChatOnline.this, "Введите ваше сообщение",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if(messageUser.length()>= MAX_LENGTH_MESSAGE){
                Toast.makeText(ChatOnline.this, "Максимальная длина сообщения 200 символов",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return ;
            }
             myRef.push().setValue(messageUser);
        /*    myRef.push().setValue(new ChatModel(
                    inputMessage.getText().toString()
            )); */
            inputMessage.setText("");

        }
    });
    myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
            String msg = snapshot.getValue().toString();
            messages.add(msg);
            chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            recyclerMessage.smoothScrollToPosition(messages.size());

          //  String loginUser = snapshot.child("login").getValue().toString();
            
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

}
```

А вот код моего адаптера:

```
    public class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolderMesssages> {

    public Context mContext;
    public ArrayList<String> messages;
    public LayoutInflater inflater;

    public TextView loginChat;
    public FirebaseDatabase database;
    public DatabaseReference rootReference;
    public String currentUserID;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseUser currentUser;

    public ChatAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

 
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolderMesssages onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_messsage,parent,false);
       return new ViewHolderMesssages(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderMesssages holder, int position) {
        String msg = messages.get(position);

        holder.message.setText(msg);
       // holder.loginChat.setText();

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messages.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Например, Вы можете добавить юзера перед отправкой сообщения в базу данных: myRef.push().setValue(currentUser.getEmail() + messageUser);

Comment: Я может что-то не так понял...просто в базе и так есть зарегистрированные пользователи. Я в начале думал просто получить ник пользователя в главном классе через snapshot, поместить значение в переменную и эту переменную передать в адаптер, но во-первых у меня постоянно писало что значение пустое, а во-вторых меня не покидало чувство что это не правильный способ реализации.

Comment: С каждого устройства сообщения пишет текущий user. Он и будет прикрепляться к сообщению. Как-то так.

Comment: Да, уже понял. Даже затестил и работает все)Спасибо вам большое. Единственное что меня смущает, что оно выводиться вместе с сообщением, а если мне надо что бы логин помещался в отдельный TextView (в котором уже прописаны стили для него) этот способ не подходит?

Comment: Можно закодить все что-угодно. =) Но правильнее, на мой взгляд, сделать сообщения в виде отдельного класса, где будут поля user, message, time. Тогда будет проще извлекать необходимые данные. Посмотрите мой репозиторий с примером на Гитхаб (ссылка в профиле).

Comment: Я новичок на StackOveerflow, но у вас наверное там где ссылка на ваш гит должна быть написано "Видимо, этот участник предпочёл окутать себя завесой тайны."

Comment: Ссылка должна быть справа под количеством ответов и вопросов.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за терпение =) изучу ваш пример.